# Disabling a global mode (whitespace-style/mode) temporarily in a buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
;; Highlight lines longer than 100 characters                         
(setq whitespace-line-column 100)
(setq whitespace-style '(face lines-tail trailing))
(global-whitespace-mode 1)
```

This basically highlights characters that are exceeding 100 characters in a line. I would like to disable that temporarily in some buffers. I've tried `M-x set-variable` and to set the style or increasing the line column, but that doesn't take effect. I also tried disabling the global-white-space-mode but no luck.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Both `whites-space-mode` and `global-whitespace-mode` are toggles. Bind either or both to keys, for convenience, if you want. Repeat `global-whitespace-mode` to turn it off everywhere.  Or use `whitespace-mode` (twice) to toggle it off in just the current buffer.

Comment: I did run each of `global-whitespace-mode` and `whitespace-mode` twice but the highlights are still there. Why would this happen? Any idea what else I can do to disable it?

Comment: One way to tell what is happening is to look at the modeline, which shows a capital *WS* for global and a lowercase *ws* for local.

Comment: Dunno; it worked for me. Did you try it starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If it workds for `emacs -Q` then bisect your init file recursively until you find whatever is interfering. If it doesn't work from `emacs -Q`, perhaps there is an Emacs bug on your platform (but I doubt it).